# How to get the middle path in a url

Tags: python, path, roblox

How to get the marked id in this url with python. Because I couldn't find anything that shows how to get the middle path of the url or just the id of it "www.roblox.com/catalog/**6906155619**/Real-Madrid-Home-Kit-21-22-SS-Benzema"?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Have you looked at the `split` method of `str` objects? Or at the `parents` attribute of `Path` objects?

Comment: If you were to do this by hand and get the IDs from a bunch of URLs, how would you do it? What tools do you need to do the same in code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.